# How to remove search providers in late 2014 Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search, firefox-extensions

The latest Firefox (now v. 34) has changed the way it administers search providers, so that  [they can be selected or un-selected, also new ones can be added, but they cannot be removed](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-bar-add-change-manage-search-engines-firefox).

That is annoying me because I use the addon [Context search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/context-search/) which gives a context menu search option for the selected text which now shows all the search engines ever added, even the ones added multiple times.

How to remove (not just un-select) some search engines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In Windows:

- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins`
- Remove all XML files except for the ones you want to keep

Here is mine:

[image]

And my FF search choices now:

[image]

---

### In Ubuntu:

The XML files for the default search engines were located in `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale`, while the ones added by the user in `/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/some_profile_folder.default/searchplugins`.

Comment: that's a good hint for me although I am not in Windows, but in Ubuntu

Comment: @cipricus I'm sure you'll have zero trouble. These are simply XML files so I can't imagine a reason they would not use the same structure in a Linux envronment

Comment: I will edit your answer to add the paths for Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

...and if you have added any in Windows 7 that you want removed, they will be found here: C:\Users(User Name)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\kmyog13g.default\searchplugins

Comment: Well, the profile name will differ. Other than that, you’re right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 43 now allows removal of the custom search engines.

1. Click on the magnifying glass in the Search bar on your toolbar, then click 'Change Search Settings'.
   [image]
2. Click on the search engine you don't want.
3. Click the 'Remove' button to take it off your list.
   [image]

<sup>Source: [Mozilla Support - Add or remove a search engine in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox#w_remove-search-engines_2)</sup>

---

For versions of Firefox prior to 43, see the [previous version of this answer here](https://superuser.com/revisions/852124/1).