# Firefox 55 - how to remove every single search engine?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Ever since updating to Firefox 55, typing in the address bar brings up an annoying "Search with Google" option at the bottom of the address bar.

When I type something, this happens:

[image: When I type something, this happens]

In `Options > Search`, I have removed as many search engines as possible, under the `One-click Search Engines`. The last one, be it Google or something else, is not removable.

This is my `Options > Search` menu:
[image: This is my Options > Search menu]

The `Default Search Engine` drop-down list only contains Google.

This renders the use of Firefox 55 an *extreme* annoyance since I have my address bar configured to give me my bookmarks only.

I would like to know how to remove every single search engine from Firefox 55.

ADDENDUM

I am using a sixty-four bit Firefox installation. The path C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser contains not the "searchplugins" folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove search providers in late 2014 Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/851345/how-to-remove-search-providers-in-late-2014-firefox)

Comment: @Ramhound Can't be a duplicate because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins` doesn't exist in Firefox 55 in Windows 10.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076935 Moved to the profile directory as of FF40

Comment: Can you put a fake search engine in there and it won't return anything?  localhost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you can't remove all search engines or at least it makes no sense for you because you can fix you problem without removing all search engines.

### How to remove the unwanted search entry in the drop-down menu:

1. Go to `about:preferences#search`
2. Uncheck `Provide search suggestions`
3. Under `One-Click Search Engines` remove the blue tick symbol for every search engine.

Now it should look like this:

[image: Example1]

4. Open `about:config`
5. Click on `I accept the risk!`
6. Search for `keyword`
7. Change the value of `keyword.enabled` to `false` by double-clicking on it

Now it should look like this:

[image: Example2]

8. Now your problem should be fixed

**Note**: Your Firefox will look a bit different than mine because I use Firefox Nightly.
Sorry for that.

Comment: This settings add this line `user_pref("browser.search.hiddenOneOffs", "Google,Yahoo,Bing,Amazon.com,DuckDuckGo,Twitter,Wikipedia (en)");` in **prefs.js** firefox user folder.

Answer (score 12):

To hide "Search for ... with:" box from the bottom of address bar autocomplete list, go to `about:config` and set `browser.urlbar.oneOffSearches` to **false**.

Comment: This is the correct trick to get back to Firefox 54 address bar - UI wise, without losing the different search engines (you can still use them if you set some keywords). This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the blue tick symbol for every search engine from One-Click Search Engines did the trick for me.